# From php table retrieve data from selected checkbox

Tags: php, html

I have below php table, it has row and column. Each row has checkbox, I am trying to retrieve `email` data from row that checkbox is selected. I can do this with Jquery, but since I can't save in text file. I am trying to do same thing with PHP. I try couple things, but none worked.

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1' bordercolor='red' id='event_table'>
<tr>
    <th> <input type='checkbox' id='chk_all' /> </th>
    <th>Id</td>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>  <input type='checkbox' id='chk[]'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] , "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: input type  should have a name

Comment: Your checkbox won't be sent with the data as it doesn't have a name, you also need to provide unique IDs. `id='chk[]'` should be `name='chk[]'`. What are you using to determine if a checkbox should be checked?

Comment: Just reread your description, you can't get the data with PHP unless you either submit the form, or do an AJAX request. JS / jQuery is your best option

Comment: @Second2None I tried `if(!empty($_POST['chk[]']))` but didn't really help

Comment: @Second2None after submit the form if I can get the data thats good enough for me. All I want is the save the data in txt file

Comment: @mtkilic it would be `if( is_array($_POST['chk']) && !empty($_POST['chk']))`

Comment: @Second2None I dont think this is working work me,  I even tried echo string after if but  didn't worked. Maybe my code base is corrupted

Comment: Have you given your input name attributes? Edit your question and post the generated form HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Hidden fields and some indentity implementation on `name=` (and `id=` as well). Here are some inputs from my end but you can modify the code as per your requirements.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>  <input type='checkbox' name='chk_".$row['id']."' id='SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE_ON_THIS_PAGE'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "<input type='hidden' name='chk_".$id."_email' value='".$row['email']."' id='SHOULD_BE_UNIQUE_ON_THIS_PAGE' /></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['car'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Here *chk_{ID}* is your main identifier while filtering data. When you submit the form, you should get to know whether checkbox is checked or not and if it is checked then you will come to know which hidden input field  has your data. Hidden fields will not appear in HTML page.

Comment: I dont quite understand what this return when form is submitted, does return with the list of emails selected?

Comment: yes, after submitting just do print_r($_POST); to see the values you posted

Comment: I get Array ( [search] => ) only

Comment: You need to put that code on <form> in order to get the submitted values

Comment: even if this print out array of emails, since its not saved in variable how can I save this in a file?

Comment: you should assign the data you want to write to a file in a variable, once you have that data you need a file handle to get this data into a file, check this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php and

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192017/discussion-between-mtkilic-and-mangesh-sathe).

Comment: I have hardcoded some data, you have to modify it. It will give you an Idea on how to make it dynamic

Answer (score 1):

As PHP is a Hypertext Preprocessor language, you can't detect any client action on your page. So here is the best solution: you must detect changes you need with JavaScript/JQuery, and then send the result to a php file via Ajax and handle the result there (In your case save it in a file);

I hope it would be helpful for you. Let me know if you have any questions